# Separate clauses or one long relative clause?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, song-lyrics, relative-clauses

The Japanese version of "[Eternal Love](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Eternal_Love)" from Final Fantasy XIII has some lyrics arranged in a way that is slightly confusing to me. For example,

> あなたとの愛が　このままずっと続きますように
> 夜空に願うの
> この手は　まだ　離せない

> あなたとの愛が　永遠であるように
> 夜空に願うの
> この手は　まだ　離せない

I don't know if the first two lines make up one whole sentence with the third line completely separate or if all three make up a long relative clause.

> どうしても甘えてしまう　もっと大人になりたいのに - I can't help but be spoiled, although I want to be more mature
> 愚痴とか弱音を吐けるのは　あなたしかいないから - Because you're the only one who I can complain and be vulnerable to

Here, I'm not sure if どうしても甘えてしまう is a complete sentence or if it's included with the following two, separated by an implicit comma since they seem to make more sense together than separate. It's the same case with these verses from "[Melodies of Life](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Melodies_Of_Life_(song)#Japanese_version)":

> めぐり逢うのは偶然と言えるの - I can say it's a coincidence that we meet each other,
> 別れる時が必ず来るのに - Even though the time will surely come when we part ways

And Innocent² from World of Final Fantasy:

> いにしえの呪文より君の声で強くなれるの　自分を好きになれる - I can become stronger from your voice than with ancient spells. I can come to like you/myself.

Does the の particle with the large space between clauses mark the end of the sentence or mark where to place a comma?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, でありますように願う is odd. So for the first two, they are rather 3 separate sentences. (To clarify: あなたとの愛が永遠であるように夜空に願うの is natural enough, but it is reasonable to think both has the same structure.)

> (I wish) my love with you would ...
>
> I wish (this) to the night sky
>
> I can't let go of this hand.

Cf.

- [Can でありますように be followed by a verb?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4164/45489)
- [どうか〜〜ますように in 「どうか異世界の出来事でありますように」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19082/45489)

---

For the third one, both are fine. It is whether you interpret the second sentence as *because* or *it's because*. Strictly speaking, the former assumes the whole is one sentence and the latter two sentences.