# ending sentences with ように

Tags: particles

I know that ように can be used like 'as' or 'like' and can also be used like 'ために'. But I was watching this TV show where they show [絵馬](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B5%B5%E9%A6%AC) and I noticed that almost all the wishes  end with ように, which I couldn't understand at first. A web search turned up [this](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100306160434AA10AGI) which says:

> if it's at the end of a sentence (or just after a verb, but that's usually at the end), it can mean you want something to happen, or like... "may x happen" or "let x happen"

My question is, could you use this in every day conversation? Like for example, if I hope our team wins, could I say: `勝ちますように`? My extremely limited experience says it sounds weird, but is it? I remember hearing ように used like this before (いい物見つかりますように) but that was in a game (and spoken by a little child) so I'm not sure if that counts.

Comment: Related: [How does this ように work?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4155/78)

Comment: `could you use this in every day conversation?` As mentioned, it's not at all uncommon to hear from actual people, but I don't know that it would come up in real conversations very much unless you're specifically wishing something to the person.  `テストうまくいきますように` = May you do well on your test / may your test go well.  But you're more likely to just hear something like `テストがんばってね！`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is extremely common to end wish-making phrases with ように.  In fact, I (a native speaker) do not know of another way of making a wish.

Everyone regardless of age or gender uses this ending.  We often add どうか for emphasis at the beginning of the phrase as well.

「（どうか）ドラゴンズが勝ちますように！」

「（どうか）花子さんと結婚できますように！」

Comment: 花子って相手ですか？ (^_^)

Comment: 私の好きな人の名前ではありません。「太郎」や「花子」は昔から例文によく使われる名前なんですよ。

Comment: どうか is kinda like 'please' right? So aside from using it in a prayer/wish, is it correct to assume that I would only say this if I am asking an indirect(?) favor from the person I'm talking to? so if the person I'm talking to is not at all involved, what should be used? I was thinking of ドラゴンズが勝つはずです but it sounds stronger and its like you're not wishing them to win but expecting them to win.

Comment: This is valid only if used with 〜ます. `勝つように` doesn't work.