# Many Usages of the term "you ni" in conversational speech

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

I am having trouble in using or interpreting a sentence that uses the japanese grammatical term 'you ni". Please don't confuse it with other grammatical structures such as 'no you ni" or "you'. This is quite confusing for me due to the fact that "you ni",based on my searches, means "so that" or something similar to it,but i listen to a sentence that uses "you ni" but i believe that the meaning "so that" doesn't fit properly.Thanks for your help!

Comment: including the sentence that is giving you trouble would help us to understand what might be causing confusion.  A common mix up is that you might be separating "you ni" from another word, which either provides  context or reveals that possibly you're actually dealing with a different grammar point than you think you are.

Comment: Can we vote to close? I don't see an actual question, and the lack of an example makes it difficult to provide a good answer. Kudos to Micheal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ending sentences with ように](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/ending-sentences-with-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab) (if this is even what you're talking about).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at this. Hopefully, this will be very informative.

I think the term you're referring to has this as a Chinese character: 様. In fact, you might want to look at this [Wiktionary page](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%A7%98).

As a na-adjective, 様/よう has two definitions:

1. be like, look like, seem like, as if, having the likeness of.
2. I hope, I pray, may. (written as ように at the end of the sentence).

Here are the conjugations of 様な/ような:

- The imperfective stem form is 様だろ/ようだろ.
- The continuative stem form is 様で/ようで.
- The terminal stem form is 様だ/ようだ.
- The attributive stem form is 様な/ような.
- The hypothetical stem form is 様なら/ようなら.
- The imperative stem form is 様であれ/ようであれ.
- The informal negative construction is 様ではない/ようではない. A variant is 様じゃない/ようじゃない.
- The informal past construction is 様だった/ようだった.
- The informal negative past construction is 様ではなかった/ようではなかった. A variant is 様じゃなかった/ようじゃなかった.
- The formal construction is 様です/ようです.
- The formal negative construction is 様ではありません/ようではありません. A variant is 様じゃありません/ようじゃありません.
- The formal past construction is 様でした/ようでした.
- The formal negative past construction is 様ではありませんでした/ようではありませんでした. A variant is 様じゃありませんでした/ようじゃありませんでした.
- The conjunctive construction is 様で/ようで.
- The conditional construction is 様なら（ば）/ようなら（ば）.
- The provisional construction is 様だったら/ようだったら.
- The volitional construction is 様だろう/ようだろう.
- The adverbial construction is 様に/ように.
- The degree construction is 様さ/ようさ.