# Do people only end sentences with ように after the -ます form?

Tags: politeness, sentence-final-particles, formality

Someone left a comment on the answer to this [ending sentences with ように](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13486/ending-sentences-with-%e3%82%88%e3%81%86%e3%81%ab) question saying that it only works with the -ます form.

I tried looking up （どうか）～ように。sentences and all the ones I found were in the -ます form, like this page http://jp.wordmind.com/ecmaster-cgi/Jsearch.cgi?kwd=%A4%DE%A4%B9%A4%E8%A4%A6%A4%CB, so is it true?

Are there exceptions? Are there other particles like this? Why is it the case if it's true?

Thank you~

Comment: ～ますように expresses *hope*, while ～するように is a *command*.

Answer (score -1):

Since「するように」and「あるように」are valid, I guess you are talking about the -です form.

The word before 〜ように should be in 連体形.

However, です's 連体形 are only used before ので or のに.

I think there are no logical explanation for this.

Comment: `The word before 〜ように should be in 連用形` <- 「連**体**形」ではないでしょうか。