# In the next sentence she wants to heal her wounds herself or she wants them to be healed?

Tags: translation

The sentence is as follows:

私が付けた傷が、少しでも癒えますようにって。

In hopes that the pain I've caused you will be eased, even if it's only by a tiny bit.

Or

Let me heal the wounds that I caused you, even a little.

The previous sentence was あなたのことを気遣ってると思いこむことで、逃げてるんだよ。

Comment: Related (usage of ように here): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4155/5010 This is also why she suddenly used the polite masu-form before ように.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm leaning toward the former. The important thing here is the transitivity of the verb is - we have 癒える and not 癒やす, with the former being intransitive (自動詞) and the latter being transitive (他動詞). For some very simplified example sentences, you'd see usages like

> 私の傷が癒えます (My wounds will heal)

vs

> 私はあなたの傷を癒やします (I will heal your wounds)

Consequently, the way it's written, it sounds like it's about wounds healing on their own. At the very least if the author wanted to express the idea that the subject of the sentence was going to heal those wounds, they intentionally chose not to.

Comment: One question, the next sentence she says is the same? The sentence is 私が奪った幸せを、いつか取り戻してくれますようにって。 which would be: In hopes that one day, you'll be able to regain some of the happiness that I stole from you. Yet again she's not the one healing but the wounds will heal on its own?

Comment: It's the same in the sense that it sounds to me like she/he's talking about this other person regaining happiness on their own. Not a verb transitivity issue in this case, but an implied subject for the verb 取り戻せる like いつか（あなたが）取り戻してくれますように. The くれる usage just seems to be about implying how much she/he wants this other person to regain their happiness.

Comment: "The くれる usage just seems to be about implying how much she/he wants this other person to regain their happiness." How much is it?

Comment: I can't really give you a concrete qualification of that; you need a native speaker to speak to something that nuanced, and at some point it's subjective anyway. All I can say is that it's more than if くれる weren't there.

Comment: くれ is the reason I translated it as "in hopes that" (she hopes so). You think my translation of the sentence was accurate

Comment: Disclaimer that I'm not a professional translator, but that certainly seems like a fine translation for the combination of ように and くれる.

Comment: Thank you very much for everything, you solved my doubts