# Pronouns in this sentence

Tags: translation, transitivity

Context:

> 彼女を、守ってあげてね？ 昔のわたし、救ってあげてね？
>   あなたは、治せる人を治してあげてね。わたしの傷はもう…あなたには専門外だから

Problem sentence:

> そう…あなただけには、もう癒すことができないんだから

Who can't be healed anymore, the person talking or the person it is being said to?

Comment: Looks strange because of the には, so I'm not sure what's the object here. But if it helps, this is the transitive version of heal (癒やす) while your [older question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46882/in-the-next-sentence-she-wants-to-heal-her-wounds-herself-or-she-wants-them-to-b) was about the intransitive heal (癒える)

Comment: This sentence comes from a completely different context though. And thanks XD

Comment: Anyways, the previous sentences were 彼女を、守ってあげてね？
昔のわたし、救ってあげてね？ and あなたは、治せる人を治してあげてね。わたしの傷はもう…あなたには専門外だから. After that comes そう…あなただけには、もう癒すことができないんだから

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the previous sentence you gave, I think it means that あなた cannot heal the wounds of わたし anymore.

In the previous sentence, わたし is talking about (her?) wounds. The wounds carry over to the next sentence, are the object of the transitive verb 癒す. The subject is あなた, but that was clear from the sentence in question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I got from the context as well. Thanks XD How would you translate the sentence then?

Comment: literally something like "That's right... only to you, (my wounds) are already unhealable"

Comment: She's telling him to go heal people who he can heal. Her wounds are already out of his "area of expertise". No idea about **昔**のわたし

Comment: oh, she had previously said that the new girl was just like her a few years ago, that's why. Last request (to make sure I understood well everything). How would you translate あなたは、治せる人を治してあげてね。わたしの傷はもう…あなたには専門外だから

Comment: It's already in the previous comment loosely, but "You, go heal people who you can heal. My wounds are already... out of your area of expertise."

Comment: I see thanks XD Considering how much she fought for him (and how much she bitterly cries when his heart loves the other girl more) I'd say she's just saying that to reassure him.