# The use of かります in a sentence

Tags: translation, words, parsing

This is the sentence I'm having troubles with:
シェリーちゃんが助かりますよーに!

I know that シェリーちゃん is Sherry-chan and,
助 is help/rescue/assist. The only part I want to know about is the かりますよーに。I have been searching the meaning of かります and the meaning that shows up is 'borrow' which is odd because it doesn't match the meaning of the sentence. The google translated version is: Sherry is saved. Which is also odd because 'Sherry' wasn't saved yet (in the video I was watching). So I was thinking it meant 'I am going to save Sherry' or 'I must save Sherry'. Also, the 
よーに part, please explain it to me.

THANK YOU VERY MUCH TO THE PEOPLE WHO TOOK THEIR PRECIOUS TIME TO ANSWER MY QUESTION!

**My mistake, it was に, not こ and り, not い。I also edited the other parts. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Where did this sentence come from? Is it possible for you to take a picture of it and add that to the question?

Comment: 助かいますよーこ makes no sense. Isn't it 助か**り**ますよー**に**? Are you still learning hiragana, or is this a bad handwritten sentence?

Comment: This is just something I picked up off a video. I did not make the sentence. That is why I'm asking about it.

Comment: Okay, so please double-check if it says what naruto suggested, and if you still have questions about that sentence then please update the question.

Comment: Got it, already edited. Thank you.

Comment: And the character after か should be り (RI), not い (I). Please triple-check.

Answer (score 7):

The verb in this sentence is [助かる【たすかる】](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8A%A9%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B) ("to be saved"). 借りる【かりる】 ("to borrow") is irrelevant.

> シェリーちゃんが助かりますよーに!
>   I hope Sherry will be saved!

- **シェリーちゃん**: Sherry(-chan)
- **が**: (subject marker)
- **助かります**: masu-form of the intransitive verb 助かる ("to be saved")
- **よーに**: a casual/slangy rendering of ように, which is used to make a wish. See: [ending sentences with ように](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13486/5010) and [How does this ように work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4155/5010)

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't think the kanji you identified is acting as its own word,  my hunch is that the actual word you are looking for is 「助｛たす｝かります」. This is an intransitive verb that means to be saved, to be escape harm, or to be helped. see [jsiho](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8A%A9%20%E3%81%9F%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B).

The injection of a non-relative-temporal noun right before a verb without a particle when more polite －ます　form is being used typically doesn't happen. Also the －ます　form is the non-past tense, so my interpretation would be that this is a plea by whoever is saying this for Sherry to escape or evade harm.

As for the よーこ、よ　is usually an assertive sentence ending particle used when talking about something you know for sure, or you want the listener to "accept" what you are saying. That is probably not the most precise explanation, but others may be able to expand on that part.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!